# string vs []byte type definition

Tags: arrays, string, go, types

If I have this code, it works as expected:

```
package main
import "strconv"

type text []byte

func main() {
   hello := text("hello")
   _ = strconv.AppendQuote(hello, " world")
}
```

but this code fails:

```
package main
import "strconv"

type text string

func main() {
   hello := text("hello")
   // cannot use hello (type text) as type string in argument to strconv.Quote
   _ = strconv.Quote(hello)
}
```

Why does one pass and the other fail? I checked the docs [1], but I didnt see
anything that explained the difference.

1. https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_definitions

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is under Assignability:

https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability

In particular:

> x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a defined type.

In both cases, the underlying types are equal (`[]byte` is required and `text` is passed in case 1, `string` is required and `text` is passed in case 2), but `[]byte` is not a defined type and `string` is, so it works for the first case, but not the second.

Answer (score 3):

You need to piece together several definitions from the language specifications to understand what's going on:

First is [Assignability](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Assignability):

> x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a defined type.

Then you need to examine your V and T.

In your first code snippet you have `type text []byte` (the V) and a function `AppendQuote` whose required argument is `[]byte` (the T).

Do V and T have identical underlying types? Yes. `text`'s underlying type is `[]byte` by your definition, and `[]byte` is a composite type, whose underlying type is itself. From [Types](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Types):

> Each type T has an underlying type: If T is one of the predeclared boolean, numeric, or string types, **or a type literal**, the corresponding underlying type is T itself

and the paragraph just above that:

> Composite types —[...]  **slice**, [...] — may be constructed using type literals.

And, is at least one of V or T **not** a defined type? Yes, `[]byte` as stated above is a composite type.

Hence a variable of type `text` is assignable to `[]byte`, including passing arguments to a function.

---

In your second code snippet you have `type text string` (the V) and a function `Quote` whose required argument is `string` (the T).

Do V and T have identical underlying types? Yes. One by definition, and the other one is the predeclared type `string` (same quote as above).

Finally, is at least one of V or T **not** a defined type? **No!** Both are defined types. `text` is defined by you and `string` is defined by the language specs in [String types](https://go.dev/ref/spec#String_types):

> The predeclared string type is string; it is a defined type.

So assigning `text` to `string` does not meet the conditions for assignability and it gives a compiler error.

Answer (score -2):

`AppendQuote` accept `[]byte` as argurment and your `hello` is defined as `text` type which is a `[]byte` from your type definition, that is why it works.

`func strconv.AppendQuote(dst []byte, s string) []byte` [see source code](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#AppendQuote)

while Quote accepts string as argument,

`func strconv.Quote(s string) string` [see source code](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#Quote)

And your hello type is `[]byte`, not string. that's why it didn't work. you will either have to use the first case, or change your hello into string. e.g. `_ = strconv.Quote("hello")` in order for it to work.

Comment: You seem to have missed the point of the question. See Burak's answer, it correctly answers what's being asked.

Comment: yes, thank you for bring that up. I see what he is looking for now. nevertheless, I see Go is a very strong type language, so my explanation although didn't exactly address what he is looking for, but state the reason why it's not working. It's just similar to dress code, if you wear the wrong attire, the bouncer won't let you in the door. regardless if you were the owner. unless, you shows a owner badge to satisfy the rules.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/zH-u2cJk6-b